# Is it safe to send SIGUSR1 to a program, and why?

Tags: c, signals, c++

When you send `SIGUSR1` signal (say the signal handler has been set in advance) to a program while it is executing `sleep(100)`, the signal is caught correctly but `sleep(100)` is terminated just after the catch. This may mean sending a signal can forcedly terminate the internal some function.

For example, in a scientific calculation program, I would like to catch `SIGUSR1` and print the progress. But what if I happen to send the signal while statements like `has_error_occured = true` or `should_break_this_roop = true` are in execution? I think this may cause unexpected behavior.

How can I use `SIGUSR1` (and `SIGUSR2`) safely? It is known that the shell command `dd` print the progress when it catches `SIGUSR1`. Why is this safe?

---

Sample program (I executed `kill -SIGUSR1 xxxxx`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>
#include <unistd.h>

void my_handler(int signal) {
    ; //some instructions
}

void just_sleep() {
    std::cout << "sleep() starts.\n";
    sleep(100); //not wait for 100s if a signal caught
    std::cout << "sleep() ends.\n"; //executed even if a signal caught
}

int main() {

    signal(SIGUSR1, my_handler);
    just_sleep();

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should set your signal handler using [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) instead of [signal(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html), and set `SA_RESTART` in `sa_flags` if you don't want it to interrupt a blocking system call.

```
struct sigaction sa;
sa.sa_handler = your_handler;
sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, 0);
```

Or, even better than that, just handle the interrupt yourself.

If nanosleep(), etc. has returned -1, check if `errno == EINTR`, and print the progress and then redo the call (sleep() is just a wrapper for nanosleep() on linux). You will have to do this anyway if your program grows to something more complex — there's not much you can do safely from a signal handler — see [the signal-safety(7) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) on Linux.